# How to make a high scores table

Tags: php, ios, networking, webserver, backend

Without using services like Game Center or OpenFeint, what is the best way/ most common way for app developers to create a high score server for their apps? I know I could do it with an apache web server and PHP pages that can write to and read from a database, but this seems like a "quick fix" or a hack.  Is there a more "correct" way of doing this?

Comment: This question seems rather broad / opinion based as is - can you narrow down your question?

Comment: I'm sorry;  I just tried to reword it.  Is this specific, or should I edit it further?  I'm new here and I'm still trying to understand the rules about specificity.

Comment: don't ask questions that beg opinions, include code and asking if there is a better way would be fine, but your question directly asks for opinion

Comment: I'm just trying to find out if there is a standard way of doing such a thing that most developers use, or if it varies largely from app to app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  mean a  simple api ...(share  data  between server side and client side)

1 . Server side read  database  by  certain script
2 . Print  formatted data(usually  json  or xml) to a page
3 . Client side request that page by url  and handle those source data